# The Letter with Digital Stamps

Tags: graphics, letters

I would like to have the digital post stamp next to the address. for example:

[image]

However I don't get a result :(

[image]

How can i modify the design of `begin{letter}{\Poststamp\RecipientAddress}` ?

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
parskip=half
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\RecipientAddress}{Berliner Rathaus\\Rathausstraße 15\\10178 Berlin}
\newcommand{\Poststamp}{\includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{post1}\\}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{\Poststamp\RecipientAddress}
        \setkomavar{subject}{Test: Poststamp as Image}
        \opening{Hallo,}
        Text............. ..
        \closing{regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: There seems to be a built-in solution in `scrlttr2` as mentioned (in German) at https://golatex.de/scrlttr2-online-briefmarke-in-adressfeld-t11857.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To top-align the image and the address, I place the address in a `\Longunderstack` and I place the image below the baseline by a value of `-\ht\strutbox`.

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
parskip=half
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\newcommand{\RecipientAddress}{\Longunderstack[l]{Berliner Rathaus\\Rathausstraße 15\\10178 Berlin}}
\newcommand{\Poststamp}{\belowbaseline[-\ht\strutbox]{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{1200px-Posthorn_Logo_Dt_Bundespost}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{\RecipientAddress{} \Poststamp}
        \setkomavar{subject}{Test: Poststamp as Image}
        \opening{Hallo,}
        Text............. ..
        \closing{regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obtained image from https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Posthorn_Logo_Dt_Bundespost.svg/1200px-Posthorn_Logo_Dt_Bundespost.svg.png and removed the `.svg` from the name (to avoid confusing LaTeX with the double file extension).

Answer (score 2):

I am using an address block (address input on webpage) on a 'DIN A4 Normalpapier (Einlegeblatt)', which is included as background image with `eso-pic`. You can either rename the stamp pdf to `\jobname_BM` or use the optional argument of `printstamp`. This is perfect for window envelopes!

```
\documentclass[
fontsize=11pt,
paper=a4,
parskip=half
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\printstamp[1][\jobname_BM]%
{%
  \AddToShipoutPictureFG*
  {%
    \put(0,0)%
    {%
      \parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}%
      {%
        \vfill%
        \centering%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight,keepaspectratio]{#1}%
        \vfill%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}
\begin{document}
    \begin{letter}{}
        \setkomavar{subject}{Test: Poststamp as Image}
        \opening{Hallo,}
        \printstamp[stamp]
        Text...............
        \closing{regards}
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image: letter with stamp pic]

In my case the code is in a dedicated letter class derived from `scrlttr2`, so in a letter I only need the `\KOMAoptions{addrfield=false}` and `\printstamp` macros.

Anonymized ;-) example for the stamp with address block:

[image: stamp with address block]